# An exception raised in the TRttiType.GetMethods function in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, rtti

Version: C++Builder 10.1
Compiler: bcc32c

---

While using a library written in Delphi, an exception has occurred in TRttiType.GetMethods function.
I tried separately test the function, it causes the same exception.
Below is the code used in the test.
What's the problem in a class of C++Builder.

Unit1.cpp:

```
#include <memory>
#include "Unit2.hpp"

class PACKAGE TCpp : public TDelphi // new class derived from delphi class
{
__published:
    void __fastcall Proc2(void);
};
void __fastcall TCpp::Proc2(void)
{
    Proc();
}

inline int __fastcall GetMethodCount(TClass AClass)
{
    const _STD unique_ptr<TRttiContext> LContext(_STD make_unique<TRttiContext>());
    return LContext->GetType(AClass)->GetMethods().Length; // GetMethods raise exception
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    ShowMessage(GetMethodCount(__classid(TDelphi))); // safe
}
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    ShowMessage(GetMethodCount(__classid(TCpp))); // exception
}
```

Unit2.pas:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

type
  TDelphi = class
  published
    procedure Proc;
  end;

implementation

{ TDelphi }

procedure TDelphi.Proc;
begin
  Sleep(0);
end;

end.
```

Comment: What version of C++Builder are you using?  The code you showed works fine for me in XE2.  `GetMethodCount(__classid(TDelphi))` returns 34, and `GetMethodCount(__classid(TCpp))` returns 35.  That being said, you should be checking the return value of `TRttiContext::GetType()` for a NULL pointer before calling `GetMethods()` on it. Also, you do not need to allocate `TRttiContext` dynamically on the heap, it works just fine on the stack.

Comment: Oh, I didn't consider the build environment. I use 10.1.
When I run again with classic compiler, it works well.
But, with clang, raise exception.

Comment: That kind of information should have been in the question.  In any case, the new bcc32c compiler has a lot of problems in general, including issues with RTTI.  Many would consider it not really production-ready at this stage.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks good information, @RemyLebeau .